# Difficulty running a command at startup

Tags: startup, touchpad, xinput

I'm using Xfce in Linux, and I need to run the following command at every startup, otherwise my touchpad is impossible to use: `xinput --set-prop 13 'Synaptics Finger' 12, 12, 0`

I've put the command in a shell script which works fine if I manually execute it.

The problem I'm having is making it run on startup. I can't add it to /etc/rc.local, because this is executed before X starts, and an xinput command won't work without X started. Also, I can't place the script in my startup programs (i.e. by placing it in a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart), because things here are executed only after I log in. But I want to use my touchpad to log in, and I can't use it until after the xinput script has been run.

So is there any way I can run the script on startup before I log in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the place to do that would be your display manager. For example, if you use `gdm3`, you can drop that line of code into

```
/etc/gdm3/Init/display
```

To quote the man page `gdm3(8)`:

> When managing a display, gdm3 attempts to execute
>          /etc/gdm3/Init/display

**Edit**

An even better place to put that bit of code would be your `xinitrc`. On my Debian box, for example, this lives under `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`.

Comment: Is adding the line to `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` preferable to adding it to `~/.xinitrc` or `~/.xsession`?

Comment: @EmmaV for your personal computer, it shouldn't make much of a difference. The only difference that I know of is that putting it in your home affects your user account only.